# Use DataTable.Select to load a cboBox

Tags: .net, powershell

I have a cboBox that I want to load with a table that I have in the script.

```
$dtNetworks = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
[void]$dtNetworks.Columns.Add("Environment")
[void]$dtNetworks.Columns.Add("Name")
[void]$dtNetworks.Columns.Add("Subnet")
[void]$dtNetworks.Rows.Add("Dev","Inside","10.0.00.0/24")
[void]$dtNetworks.Rows.Add("Dev","DMZ","10.0.0.0/24")
[void]$dtNetworks.Rows.Add("QA","Inside","10.1.0.0/24")
[void]$dtNetworks.Rows.Add("QA","DMZ","10.1.0.0/24")
[void]$dtNetworks.Rows.Add("Prod","Inside","10.2.0.0/24")
[void]$dtNetworks.Rows.Add("Prod","DMZ","10.2.0.0/24")

$WPFtxt_dNetwork.DisplayMemberPath = "Name"
$WPFtxt_dNetwork.SelectedValuePath = "Subnet"
#$WPFtxt_dNetwork.ItemsSource = $dtNetworks.DefaultView
$WPFtxt_dNetwork.ItemsSource = $dtNetworks.Select("Environment = 'Dev'")
$WPFtxt_dNetwork.SelectedIndex = 1
$form.Activate()
```

The $dtNetworks.DefaultView works and populates the cboBox with all of the values in $dtNetworks. It also returns a System.Data.DataRowView type.

The select statement works on it's own and returns just the Dev values, but it returns a System.Data.DataRow type. The cboBox has no entries in it when the form is filled.

Any ideas how I can filter the contents of $dtNetworks into a DataRowView?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using the `.Select()` method to define your source, keep the source as the DefaultView, and apply a filter to that view.

```
$dtNetworks = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
[void]$dtNetworks.Columns.Add("Environment")
[void]$dtNetworks.Columns.Add("Name")
[void]$dtNetworks.Columns.Add("Subnet")
[void]$dtNetworks.Rows.Add("Dev","Inside","10.0.00.0/24")
[void]$dtNetworks.Rows.Add("Dev","DMZ","10.0.0.0/24")
[void]$dtNetworks.Rows.Add("QA","Inside","10.1.0.0/24")
[void]$dtNetworks.Rows.Add("QA","DMZ","10.1.0.0/24")
[void]$dtNetworks.Rows.Add("Prod","Inside","10.2.0.0/24")
[void]$dtNetworks.Rows.Add("Prod","DMZ","10.2.0.0/24")

$WPFtxt_dNetwork.DisplayMemberPath = "Name"
$WPFtxt_dNetwork.SelectedValuePath = "Subnet"
$dtNetworks.DefaultView.Filter = "Environment = 'Dev'"
$WPFtxt_dNetwork.ItemsSource = $dtNetworks.DefaultView
$WPFtxt_dNetwork.SelectedIndex = 1
$form.Activate()
```